CTkTable .configure of Row and Column Atribute
I have code as below an my problem is why the .configure always end on the error

KeyError: (2, 0)

import customtkinter
from CTkTable import *

root = customtkinter.CTk()

value = [
        "Lunch",
        "Private",
        "Teambulding",
        "Teambuilding",
        "Home Office",
        "Car Blocker",
        "Grilovačka",
        "Christmas party",
        "Deadline pro TimeSheet",
        "KONTROLA DOCHÁZKY",
        "Save the date ",
        "On-Call Duty",
        "TimeSheets - Upload"]

Show_Skip_Events_list = []
for skip_Subject in value:
    Show_Skip_Events_list.append([skip_Subject])


# Working code
table1 = CTkTable(master=root, column=1, row=len(value), values=Show_Skip_Events_list)
table1.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=20, pady=20)

# Not Working code
table2 = CTkTable(master=root)
table2.configure(columns=1, rows=len(value), values=Show_Skip_Events_list)

table2.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=20, pady=20)
root.mainloop()

I did some analyze and actually it always ended with this code in CTkTable:

I already registered it on GitHub for the author to take a look but I need to find all possible source of help.
